# What is included for canon for the new Batman Beyond Unlimited comics?

Tags: dc, batman-beyond

For possible canon sources we have:

- The original TV series
- The original comic series
- The Return of the Joker (DVD)

In the original TV series Batman (Terry) travels to the Fortress of Solitude in the *The Call 1 & 2.* And yet in the Batman Beyond Unlimited #2 he says this while conversing with Superman.

I would think he already knows that Superman has a sort of trophy room. It is within the Fortress of Solitude.

[image]

In the same comic issue Batman (Terry) refers to how Tim Drake ended his crime-fighting career originally. Is he referring to the events of The Return of the Joker? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in that he's referring to the events of *Return of the Joker*. The canon for the new *Batman Beyond* series ought to be surprisingly large.  It would contain as a start:

- Batman Beyond (tv series)

But that series was part of the larger [DC Animated Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe) of the 90's and 00's.  That means the canon should also include:

- Batman: The Animated Series (1992–1995)
- Batman: Mask of the Phantasm (1993)
- Batman & Mr. Freeze: SubZero (1998)
- Superman: The Animated Series (1996–2000)
- The New Batman/Superman Adventures (1997–2000):

  - Superman: The Animated Series (1996–2000)
  - The New Batman Adventures (1997–1999)
- Batman Beyond (1999–2001)
- Batman Beyond: Return of the Joker (2000)
- Justice League (2001–2004)
- Batman: Mystery of the Batwoman (2003)
- Justice League Unlimited (2004–2006)

(I've pruned the series that probably will never come up in the Batman Beyond series, but I expect there to be references to the old Justice League adventures and villains.  The complete listing is in my link above.)